# How to fly under the radar when you are just waiting for your stock to vest?

Tags: employee-engagement

I am a disengaged employee who can't be bothered to try anymore but I have stock which is a large part of my compensation so I will be hanging around until at least November.

My reasons are the usual combo of problems with management and seeing no real future for me in the company.

I am not going to do nothing. I will do the tasks assigned to me. I just don't plan to do much beyond the parceled out work at planning. I will just nod in architecture meetings.

Any other tips for getting away with this?

Comment: this looks like a rehash of several recent questions, one example that springs to mind is [How to disappear at work?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/174411/168)

Comment: Sounds like you know how to run out the clock.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two specific tips:

1. Use the "hero item".  Say there is some project ongoing. Do *one really clever thing* on it. (This may involve you, you know, "working all day" on it, but it will save you weeks of work subesequently.)  If you solve some nagging problem, or deliver that little key piece, you'll be "seen to be doing" a lot of work and then you can coast for a few weeks.
2. Deliver something early. If there is a project, chunk or work, subsystem, make an early effort and show something that kicks off the project.  Again, you'll then be "seen to be doing" a lot of work and then you can coast for a few weeks on that.

Hope it helps.

## Very importantly...

Notice the comment above: *"keep your intentions and your opinions about the company completely to yourself"*

Completely as in 1000%, say *nothing, ever, about anything*.

Comment: I used 1 on my previous job. I picked up a few tasks that had a lot of hours assigned, but I knew I could do in only a few. It appeared as if I was doing a lot of work, when I actually wasn't. It's not necessarily honest, but I had no loyalty left for the company after they made it very clear they didn't have any towards me either. It's all about appearances at that point.

Answer (score 5):

**Have a steady stream of achievements, even if minor and trivial, and make them visible.**

I did this when I worked on a team where I wanted to report progress every day during standup as otherwise people would bother me. I would have little bugs that I would solve if I knew I was not going to deliver my big thing that day and report that I was working on that or had just finished that.

I could have taken the rest of the day off and achieved nothing as I had my progress report at standup. The appearance of progress is what is important here.